# BigQuery: Using contains_substr (or equivalent) on an array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am interacting with Google Cloud billing data, exported to BigQuery, and I am trying to create a view with some additional fields.  The billing export has some nested fields.  I want to interact with this information in Looker Studio, and these nested fields create some problems in Looker Studio.

I'm trying to use case statements coupled with contains_substr to add a column with the cost value if the sku.description has "commit" in the name, and the credits.amount values if the credits.type has "commit" in the name.  I've got the first statement to work, but can't get the credits.amount statement to work because it's an array.

I have succeeded in getting it to run a query like this:

```
select *,
    case when contains_substr(sku.description, 'commit') then cost else 0 end as CUD_charges,
    from `gcp_billing_export_resource_v1_017XXX_969XXX_BE9XXX` s
    WHERE _PARTITIONDATE > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
```

But if I try to add:

```
case when contains_substr(credits.type, 'commit') then credits.amount else 0 end as CUD_credits,
```

I get told that it "Cannot access field type on a value with type ARRAY."

Is there a way to do this, perhaps using UNNEST?

EDIT:
If I try to run:

```
select *, 
    case when contains_substr(cr.credits.type, 'commit') then cr.credits.amount else 0 end as CUD_credits
    from `gcp_billing_export_resource_v1_017XXX_969XXX_BE9XXX` s,
    UNNEST(credits) AS cr
    WHERE _PARTITIONDATE > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

I get: Field name credits does not exist in STRUCT<name STRING, amount FLOAT64, full_name STRING, ...> at [2:34]

For reference, here is what the credit info looks like for one row of data:
[image: One row of credit info]

Comment: con you please add some rows of sku.description

Comment: yes, UNNEST.  can you try this?

select *, case when contains_substr(cr.credits.type, 'commit') then cr.credits.amount else 0 end as CUD_credits
from `gcp_billing_export_resource_v1_017XXX_969XXX_BE9XXX` s, UNNEST(credits) AS cr
WHERE _PARTITIONDATE > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)

Comment: @smoore4 Thanks so much for your response.  I added an edit above, but am still encountering an error.

Comment: @nbk Thanks for your response.  The data is so unwieldy, with so many columns, and the nested fields make it look like garbage.  I did include a screenshot of one row of credit information.  But it's otherwise hard to present what it looks like.

Comment: the image is unreadable, please add the text as text